# adding records to table without specifing the foreign key

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in my database :

```
-etudiant(id(PK),nom,prenom,tel,adresse,filiere(FK))
-filiere(id(PK),libelle)
```

In the `etudiant` table I have a foreign key `filiere` which references the table `filiere`.

Sometimes I want to add records to etudiant table without specifing the foreign key filiere, but I get this error message when I do that :

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`gecole`.`etudiant`, CONSTRAINT `etudiant_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`filiere`) REFERENCES `filiere` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE
>   CASCADE)

Comment: from your question, what I understood is the foreign key can be empty sometimes. For achieving that, you've to allow the foreign key  field (`filiere` in the `etudiant` table) to be `NULL` and set `DEFAULT NULL` also using the phpmyadmin or mysql terminal. Otherwise it'll check for foreign key constraints.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because you're trying to add/update a row to `etudiant table` that does not have a valid value for the `etudiant_ibfk_1` field based on the values currently stored in `filiere`. If you post some more code I can help you diagnose the specific cause.

**Update :**

Try DISABLE KEYS or

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

make sure to

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

after.

Comment: I know what the problem is, in this post I said that I want to add a new record without specifying the foreign key.

Comment: @YukinaSpoonatte I think i haven't read your question carefully . Please check the updated answer . I hope it is what you want .